# Overwrote passwd file; unable to login to fix it

Tags: password

I am running Red Hat Enterprise Linux ES release 4 (Nahant Update 8). The `/etc/passwd` file was overwritten by mistake. I have a backup copy of the original passwd file, but when I try to log in as root, or admin, I am denied access. How can I log back into the server and replace the passwd file with the original?

Comment: Passwords are usually stored in /etc/shadow, what *exactly* is the error message you see?

Comment: Do you have a recovery CD?

Comment: I would boot from a Linux on CD/USB and create a new /etc/passwd, or restore it from backup. If booting like that is not possible, remove the system HD and mount it on a different machine (e.g. via an USB enclosure) and restore `/etc/passwd`

Comment: Can you access GRUB and modify the kernel boot arguments? Passing `init=/bis/sh` would launch `sh` instead of the default `init` on the readonly mounted root filesystem. You then can remount the root FS to be writable and restore a backup of the passwd file. If that sounds like black magic to you, better look for a rescue CD...

Comment: I have a Linux ES Bootable CD, will that work for a rescue CD?  Novice. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need rescue mode of your linux dist

you didn't say what dist you're on but here's an example for Fedora/RH/CentOS:
http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_reset_a_root_password

Comment: I am on a Red Hat Ent. Linux ES release 4 (Nahant Update 8)

Comment: the link I gave above should work for RH but I found some RH-specific links too:

[link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Step_by_Step_Guide/s1-q-and-a-root-passwd.html)

[link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/System_Administration_Guide/ch-rescuemode.html#s2-rescuemode-root-password)

good luck!